# Why router navigates me into homepage when i'm changing my query params in url reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I work with React Router V5.

I have implemented React Pagination with url params.

I'm facing issue when i'm changing my query params in url then router redirects into homepage.

Could you tell me what is wrong with my routes?

```
export const AppRoutes = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Switch>
      {!currentUser.isLoggedIn && <Route path={AppRoute.login} component={Login} />}
      <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Redirect to='/' />
      </Layout>
    </Switch>
```

When i comment redirect line, then my pagination with params works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `path={AppRoute.login}` path isn't matched and rendered by the `Switch` component the ***entire*** `Layout` component is rendered, then all routes inside are ***inclusively*** matched and rendered just like they would be in a router outside any `Switch` component.

In other words, the `Redirect` is always matched and rendered, redirecting unconditionally to `"/"`.

You can render the nested routes inside another `Switch` so ***exclusive*** route matching and rendering occurs:

```
export const AppRoutes = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Switch>
      {!currentUser.isLoggedIn && <Route path={AppRoute.login} component={Login} />}
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Redirect to='/' />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```